# Classes with same name in different namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, naming

I am writing a library. Is it a bad idea to have two classes with same name but each of the classes are in different namespace?

Using name spaces:

```
//forward declaration
namespace sparse {
    class matrix;
}
namespace dense {
    class matrix;
}

namespace dense {
    typedef Index uint64_t;
    class matrix {
        public:
        sparse::matrix tosparse();
    };
}

namespace sparse {
    typedef Index uint32_t;
    class matrix {
        dense::matrix todense();
    };
}
```

Alternatively, I can use long names:

```
class sparse_matrix
...
```

Comment: Do you trust the users of the library to not `using namespace *;`? If the answer is `no`, then it's not very safe. I would just use the long name. It's not that long anyway.

Comment: Expanding upon what @DeiDei said, it really depends upon usage. In my opinion, a lot of the time these might be used together and `dense::matrix` and `sparse::matrix` is longer than `dense_matrix` and `sparse_matrix` anyways.

Comment: Personally, I would alias long namespaces, and would never use `using namespce *;` when I use a library. But I guess that can happen......

Comment: @DeiDei If users say `using namespace whatever;` they only have themselves to blame for any mess that ensues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, that's fine. That's exactly what namespaces are for. In this example it's not clear what the design goal is, so it's not clear whether this is an appropriate use of namespaces.

Comment: I was trying namespaces to 1. make using the library easier because the user can alias namespaces like `aaa::bbb::ccc` to `abc`. 2. make writing the library involve less typing, because repeating `aaa_Index_type` a dozen times in `aaa_range`, `aaa_iterator`, etc is not fun. With the namespace, it is just `a`, `iterator`, `Index_type` in a one namespace. I am changing the `aaa::bbb::ccc` back to `aaa_bbb_ccc` now, and then in `aaa_range` use a public `typedef aaa_Index_type Index_type`. The long class names like `aaa_bbb_simd_parallel` is inconvenient to write or use, and is still a problem.

Comment: The cpp core guideline says putting helper functions in the same namespace as the main class is a good idea (https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-helper). I guess I will put the main class and the helper classes in the same name space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a bad idea.

1. more than one namespace can be included. So this amounts to writing sparse::matrix vs dense::matrix.
2. clarity is king. `sparse_matrix` tells about the behavior of that object.
3. They provide similar/the same utility to the client. Why different namespaces?

If you want them to have a common base, do inheritance (abstract or not).

Comment: It is like `sparse_matrix_stride_range`, `sparse_matrix_stride_iterator`, with `Sparse_matrix_index_type`, `Sparse_matrix_capacity.col`, `Sparse_matrix::Sparse_matrix(const Sparse_matrix_capacity& capacity);` etc... But I agree, the cons are too bad, at least for the user.

Comment: @throw_away_account That is a different problem. You can always introduce typedefs or using declarations to simplify that.

Comment: But here supports using namespace: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50120/best-practices-for-using-namespaces-in-c I figured out that nested namespace is quite painful to maintain because forward declaration is nearly impossible.

Comment: In my mind, the purpose of the namespace, is to avoid needless suffixes and prefixes which are usually used in C to avoid collisions. I think your right about this particular example, but as a general principle I would disagree. Namespaces are awesome because matrix can just be matrix.